# Software that secures streamed videos from piracy

Tags: video, security, screen-recording, streaming, zoom

Is there an app similar to ZOOM but that ensures the security of streamed videos?
For example, I was researching about this and found that this Learning Management System (LMS) has this feature (https://www.learnyst.com/content-security/drm) that benefits people with online courses. However, in my case, I am not looking for LMS, I am just looking for something similar to ZOOM for live streaming and that secures live videos from being downloaded or screen recorded by another software without permission.

Thank you.